# List Index Out Of Range Python File Directory

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import sys    
import os
if __name__ == "__main__":
    t_Argv = sys.argv #Argument
    t_FileDir = t_Argv[1]
    t_ListFiles = os.listdir(t_FileDir)
    t_Freq = t_Argv[2] # Frequency
```

I'm trying to create a file directory using arguments, but I'm also confused, why the index list is still error

Comment: How you are calling this script from cmd?

Comment: Also if you have two arguments, you acess the wrong index which is not exist.

Comment: List indices start at 0, so if you have two values you have to use `t_Argv[0]` and `t_Argv[1]`. You can check the number of values you have using `print(len(t_Argv))` and the values by `print(t_Argv)`.